# Magento 2 ,category and flush magento cache error

Tags: category, cache

magento 2.0.2

there are an error when doing flush magento cache

and we found out when the products in one of the category ,all operation around the product will error, we cant deselect that cateogry ,only we can del the product,same warning as flush magento cache error

warning, is_File() expects parameter 1 to be vaild path, string given in File.php line 508

[image][image]